# data.table : remove duplicate subset of rows for a given index value

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to improve my piece of code. Let's say you want to remove duplicate rows that have the same 'label' and 'id'. The way I do it is:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(label = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A"),
                 id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5))
tmp = dt[label == 'A',]
tmp = unique(tmp, by = 'id')
dt = dt[label != 'A',]
dt = rbind(dt, tmp)
```

Is there a smarter/shorter way to accomplish that? If possible by reference?
This code looks very ugly and implies a lot of copies.

(Moreover I have to do this operation for a few labels, but not all of them. So this implies 4 lines for every label...)

Thanks !

Example:

```
label id
A     1
A     1
B     2
B     2
C     3
A     4
A     5
A     5
```

Would give :

```
label id
A     1
B     2
B     2
C     3
A     4
A     5
```

Note that line 3 and 4 stay duplicated since the label is equal to 'B' and not to 'A'.

Comment: Because it deserves one :p
It's for the purpose of what I'm working on : Some duplicated rows are relevant, but some other are not. So I want to remove only part of them depending on their label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to create `tmp` and then `rbind` it again. You can simply use the `duplicated` function as follows:

```
dt[label != "A" | !duplicated(dt, by=c("label", "id"))]
#    label id
# 1:     A  1
# 2:     B  2
# 3:     B  2
# 4:     C  3
# 5:     A  4
# 6:     A  5
```

If you want to do this over several labels:

```
dt[!label %in% c("A", "C") | !duplicated(dt, by=c("label", "id"))]
```

See `?duplicated` to learn more about de-duplication functions in `data.table`.

Comment: Double negative's kind of weirding me out. For those in a similar circumstance: `dt[!( label == "A" & duplicated(dt, by=c("label", "id")) )]`

Answer (score 1):

This could be also done using an `if/else` condition

```
dt[, if(all(label=='A')) .SD[1L] else .SD, by = id]
#   id label
#1:  1     A
#2:  2     B
#3:  2     B
#4:  3     C
#5:  4     A
#6:  5     A
```